# Custom BaseAdapter duplicates items in ListView

Tags: android, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I have a custom adapter which inherits from BaseAdapter, and I have a ListView in a different .java file. Basically I click on a button and this calls the custom adapter. So when the app first loads the fist time I click the button, it's fine. On every subsequent click the items (retaining order) are duplicated both the number and the contents of the items. I am sure there is something wrong with the overridden getView method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {}
```

However I am not sure whether the View convertView is set to anything on when the items are ready to be displayed in the ListView. So I put a check in there:

```
if (view == null) {}
```

I think this check is the root of the problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the gist to the SharedResourcesAdapter, the custom adapter class:
https://gist.github.com/serceberka/f34c8f3339ef9e4bc9dc23d3ac8f74c4

Here is the gist to the SharedResources AppCompatActivity where the adapter gets set:
https://gist.github.com/serceberka/ea9fc73b42a9d271e6fbac7d7793667f
(You'll find it in the PageLoad class which extends AsyncTask)

Comment: Please don't just link to your code off-site. You need to include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Yes I will do that next time.

Comment: If you're not going to put the code in the question, you might as well just delete this, then.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved.

Basically there was no problem with the custom adapter itself, the issue was that I was reading the items from a List and updating the List every time a new query was sent. To fix the problem I cleared the List before a adding items to it to avoid getting duplicated items (i.e. from the same search query) or retaining items from previous queries.